# RuntimeBinderExeption when refering json object to string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize my JSON. Here is my JSON string.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "records",
        "id": "7",
        "attributes": {
            "created": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
            "updated": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
            "state": 3,
            "data": {
                "Lastname": [
                    "Gonzales"
                ],
                "Firstname": [
                    "Lacy"
                ],
                "Email": [
                    "ludam@gmail.com"
                ],
                "Salutation": [
                    "Mrs."
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I create a dynamic variable like this and assign the firstname into string s I get a RuntimebinderException.

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString2);
string s = data.attributes.data.Firstname;
```

Is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your JSON structure, `Firstname` is actually an array with a single item.

Also, since your JSON contains a root object named `data`, it seems like you're missing that too (might be confusing since you named your variable `data` as well).

I would go with:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString2);
string s = result.data.attributes.data.Firstname[0];
```

Obviously, if you're in control of the returned JSON, you may refactor it into something that is more easily consumed:

```
"FirstName": "Lacy",
```

Also, you can avoid `dynamic` altogether by accessing your data using raw `JObject`:

```
var firstName = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("data.attributes.data.Firstname[0]").ToString();
```

See [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) for more options

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your json seems to be incorrect.

Correct Json:

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "records",
    "id": "7",
    "attributes": {
        "created": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
        "updated": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
        "state": 3,
        "data": {
            "Lastname": [
                "Gonzales"
            ],
            "Firstname": [
                "Lacy"
            ],
            "Email": [
                "ludam@gmail.com"
            ],
            "Salutation": [
                "Mrs."
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

FirstName is `List<string>`, not `string`.

```
List<string> ls =  obj.data.attributes.data.Firstname;
```

Because Data2 will be serialised as.

```
public class Data2
    {
        public List<string> Lastname { get; set; }
        public List<string> Firstname { get; set; }
        public List<string> Email { get; set; }
        public List<string> Salutation { get; set; }
    }
```

One more suggestion.

I think If Data2 belongs to only one persion, then you have to change the json structure.

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "records",
    "id": "7",
    "attributes": {
        "created": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
        "updated": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
        "state": 3,
        "data": {
            "Lastname": "Gonzales",
            "Firstname": "Lacy",
            "Email": "ludam@gmail.com",
            "Salutation": "Mrs."

        }
    }
}
}
```

And If you deserialise it to class. then `Data2` class will be like this.

```
public class Data2
    {
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Salutation { get; set; }
    }
```

And then you can do, what are you currently doing.

```
string  firstName =  obj.data.attributes.data.Firstname;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is way to change your `json`, then remove that [] inside first name and so on as below. Then you can access the value.

```
    "data": {
    "type": "records",
    "id": "7",
    "attributes": {
      "created": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
      "updated": "2017-01-19T08:42:56Z",
      "state": 3,
      "data": {
        "Lastname":"Gonzales",
        "Firstname":"Lacy",
        "Email":"ludam@gmail.com",
        "Salutation":"Mrs."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or you can access without changing the `json` like @haim770 mentioned in his answer.